# How To Find Proxy is Http or Socks

Tags: http, proxy, socks

Can anyone tell me how to find the proxy server is http or socks ? Is that based on port number ? how it differs ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why do you want to know?

Comment: I'm using one application it only supports http proxy. so i want differ the proxy based on the type

Answer (score 12):

try it as http: `curl -x http://x.x.x.x:y check-host.net/ip`. if fails, try as socks: `curl -x socks://x.x.x.x:y check-host.net/ip`.

Comment: what are x.x.x.x:y values to check for?

Comment: x.x.x.x is IP and y is PORT NUMBER you want to check

Comment: @AlexanderZhak how to curl with id and password? I'm hitting authorization error...

Comment: @user1872384 please check curl documentation. It depends on auth type the service is using. You can pass username and password using `--user username:password` key or in HTTP headers, or as URI params. It depends.

Comment: Thx Alexander Zhak

Answer (score 2):

No, the proxy type is not based on port numbers. The ports are assigned by network admins and can be anything they want.

Your only hope is if your network is configured to use some type of [proxy auto-config](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_auto-config) to provide the specific proxy details to clients when needed.

Otherwise, there is no way to query the proxy itself. You have to know ahead of time what type of proxy it is so you know how to communicate with it correctly.

Answer (score -1):

Try this script:

```
$ cat get_version.py 
#!/usr/bin/python

import struct
import socket
import sys


try:
        server = sys.argv[1]
        port = sys.argv[2]
except:
        print "Usage: server port"

try:
        sen = struct.pack('BBB', 0x05, 0x01, 0x00)
        s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        s.connect(( server , int( port )  ))
        s.sendall(sen)
        data = s.recv(2)
        s.close()
        version, auth = struct.unpack('BB', data)
        print 'server : port  is  ', server, ':', port, '; varsion: ', version
except Exception as e:
        print e
```

Comment: Tools like [goproxy](https://snail007.github.io/goproxy/manual/#/?id=_63-socks5-to-httpssocks5ss) can support multiple socks5 / HTTP/HTTPS protocols on the one port, and using your code only seems to detect socks5.